# Derivation of the Probability Mass Function of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, education, math-history

The Probability Mass Function of Bernoulli distribution looks like this:

\begin{equation}
p : \mathcal{X} \to [0,1], x\mapsto p(x) := \mu^{x}(1 - \mu)^{1-x} \mbox{ for } \mu \in [0,1].
\end{equation}

I am interested in it's derivation. How did someone determine it to have exactly this form, are there any mathematical steps, which lead to this function?

Comment: What is this $\mathcal{X}$? (Note that this terminology of "Bernoulli distribution" is not what is usually meant by that phrase.)

Comment: @Ian possible output values, if I am not mistaken.

Have changed the header.

Comment: I mean yes, but what are the possible values? $\{ 0,1 \}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $\mu^x(1-\mu)^{1-x}$ is equal to $\mu$ when $x = 1$ and $1-\mu$ when $x = 0$. It's just a more compact way of writing $P[x=1] = \mu$ and $P[x=0] = 1-\mu$:

$$ P[x=0] = \mu^0(1-\mu)^{1-0} = 1-\mu , $$

$$ P[x=1] = \mu^1(1-\mu)^{1-1} = \mu . $$

Comment: I understand it, thanks.
However, what am I interested in is whether there are some formal mathematical steps that lead to this PMF. Like , for example, with the Gaussian PDF (here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTyPuZ9-JZ0).

Comment: The distribution is discrete with only two possible outcomes, that formula really just stems from the fact that it's a compact way of writing the same thing as writing out the two probabilities separately. There's no long complicated derivation, it really is as simple as it seems.

Comment: Understood, thank you.